# How to access a server connected to a University network?

Tags: linux, telnet

In my University, my professor provided us with his server address, but he said that we can only access his server through our University's wireless network.

He also said, there is a way to access his server from outside.

Our University's server is Polaris and I can connect to my university server using telnet and my user name/password.

What is the available way to browse my professor's web page from out campus that is on his own server that is connected only to the university server.

Comment: Can you only use telnet or do they allow SSH as well?  Telnet is a bit outdated an much less secure, but that is beside the point.  If you can SSH I would tunnel in (and will add an answer with how if you can).

Comment: They allow SSH but I do not know it. He also said that SSH is the way he meant. Yes please put an answer.

Comment: You'll probably should contact the university networking team and get an answer.  Having us attempt to crack the university network is not really an appropriate type of question.

Comment: @mdpc is this considered cracking?

Comment: @mdpc this isn't cracking; he's asking how to legitimately access university resources from off-campus. Setting up ssh tunneling for authorized use is neither illegal, unethical, nor "cracking".

Comment: Does your university provide some kind of a VPN? Most do ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SSH is allowed, I would do a simple SSH tunnel, something like what is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388621/tunnel-http-via-proxy-using-telnet) post.

I was going to write it all up, but found [this](http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2009/05/ssh-proxy-windows-linux-orkut-bypass.html) page that does it much better than I could have.  As a summary:

In Linux/Unix/Cygwin:

```
ssh -C2qTnN -D 9090 username@server
```

This sets up a socks proxy for it, and **requires you to then tell your browser to use port 9090** for traffic (follow the link above for that).  (9090 is used because it's a non-reserved port on the system, though typically I use 8080 which is the common alternate to the one used for normal HTTP traffic (80)).

On Windows, the link shows how to establish this via puTTY - I have tried both ways previously and had success (Cygwin on windows, in my linux terminal or using Putty).

Comment: I set up my tunnels using PuTTY via the command line (Windows) by doing "ssh -R 9090:127.0.0.1:22 username@server" where 9090 is the port I am running the tunnel over.

Comment: Definitely a good way to do it, that's how mine is currently set-up(similar, anyways).  I just didn't want to go into setting up environmental variables and such for the OP.  Thanks @ekaj